# How to make my game work?

Tags: python

```
import random
import sys

Hdie = "A human has fallen."

Zdie = "A zombie has fallen!"

No = "Nothing happened."

Randeve = (Hdie, Zdie, No)

NumH = int(raw_input("How many humans are on your team?"))

NumZ = int(raw_input("How many zombies are in the area?"))

if NumH >= 101:
    print "Maximum humans is 100."
    sys.exit()

if NumZ >= 121:
    print "Maximum zombies is 120."
    sys.exit()

print(random.choice(Randeve))

if Randeve == Hdie:
    print "hi"
```

Whenever I run it and it prints `Hdie`, it won't print `hi`. Help me!

Comment: A tuple will never be equal to a string.

Comment: If you're trying to do `if the thing I just printed is equal to Hdie, print "hi"`, then comparing Randeve to Hdie isn't going to do it

Comment: Randeve its a tuple, Hdie is a string.

Comment: You meant to write `event = random.choice(Randeve)`; then `if event == Hdie`.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Python 2.7? If you try this code in Python 3 it won't work. If so, tag the question as such.

Comment: I got lots of respect for you kid ... not many people your age can even get hello world and you are already making some great stuff ... keep it up ... unfortunately this question however is not very good (but hopefully you got your answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the result of `random.choice(Randeve)` to a variable, and use it in both places where it's applicable.

```
x = random.choice(Randeve)
print(x)
if x == Hdie:
    print "hi"
```

Comment: Sorry, before I could see your answer, I figured out my problem. Thanks anyway, Nick